# Make a alert message disappear after x time in React functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I made a expire component that allows content in it to disappear after x amount of seconds. It works by using state and setTimeout.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function Expire(props)
{
    const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() =>
    {
        setTimer(props.delay);
    }, []);


    const setTimer = (delay) =>
    {
        setTimeout(() => setIsVisible(false), delay);
    };

    return (
        isVisible
            ? <div>{props.children}</div>
            : <span />
    );
}

export default Expire;
```

I use it like this :

```js
<Expire delay="5000">
    <Alert type={alertMsgState} size="col-md-10" />
</Expire>
```

But the problem i am having is that after disappearing once after 5 seconds, when again a `alertMsgState` is changed [eg. a form is submitted again, so I want to show the alert again], the message does'nt re-render and disappear after after 5 seconds like it's supposed to. On inspecting I just see the `<span />` element.

Please answer using functional components and hooks only.

Answer (score 2):

You don't do anything that would re trigger showing the alert component again.

One solution is use an integer key for example, and when you want to show it again do something like:

```
// inside parent
const [key, setKey] = useState(0);

// Say from a click handler when you again want to show your component, do:
let onClick=()=>{
  setKey(key+1);
}

//...

<Expire delay="5000" key={key}>
    <Alert type={alertMsgState} size="col-md-10" />
</Expire>
```

**When between different renders react encounters your component with different keys, it will unmount the old component and mount it again - hence you will get the desired behavior.**

Comment: Thank you! Your solution works. But please is there an alternative that you can provide? I want to keep all the code of expire component in expire component and not make my parent component dirty with keys and stuff.

Comment: @Haris first ask yourself: when do you want your Expire component to be repainted?

Comment: Whenever child is changed, at least in this case.

Comment: @Haris Can you show example in your question how you want to consume the Expire component? Would it be easy to use if when you want to again show the Expire component you'd need to give it a different child?

Comment: I have shown in the question, I use it with an alert component now. Alert component is updated when user submits the form `alertMsgState` is the message from the form submisson that is received from the server.

Comment: But sometimes same `alertMsgState` is received twice or more times, eg. "success" is received multiple times.. or "failed", etc

Comment: @Haris So you see? when you told me "Whenever child is changed" it means this isn't true?

Comment: Oh yeah that's true! So, let's say whenever I receive a new `alertMsgState` from the server I want to re-render the expire component.

Comment: @Haris Sorry at the moment the easiest way for you to go without fully rewriting your Expire component seem to be the keys approach.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is bind a useEffect to `props.children`, so whenever this changes you reset the message, restore visibility and start the timeout again:

```
function Expire(props)
{
    const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true);
    const [children, setChildren] = useState(props.children)

    useEffect(() =>
    {
        setChildren(props.children)
        setIsVisible(true)
        setTimer(props.delay);
    }, [props.children]);


    const setTimer = (delay) =>
    {
        setTimeout(() => setIsVisible(false), delay);
    };

    return (
        isVisible
            ? <div>{children}</div>
            : <span />
    );
}
```

Comment: I made a fiddle expanding my solution and it seems to work,
https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-flower-3p49v?file=/src/App.js.
Don't know what your Alert component looks like but if it's something standard there shouldn't be problems.